# Count days worked i.e count items in python list

Tags: python

I have a list of employees who work at different times of the day, what I would like is to count the number of days every guys has worked, like so:

FOO : 3
BAZ : 3
NOM : 1 etc....

this is how I receive the raw data:

```
my_list = [('NOM', datetime.date(2030, 1, 1)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11))]
```

I managed to strip the list to unique days for each individual like so :
 `a = Counter(set(dictio))` which gets rid of the duplicates for one guy in a day:

```
Counter({('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)): 1,
         ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)): 1,
         ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)): 1,
         ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)): 1,
         ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)): 1,
         ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)): 1,
         ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)): 1,
         ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)): 1,
         ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)): 1,
         ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)): 1,
         ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)): 1,
         ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)): 1,
         ('NOM', datetime.date(2030, 1, 1)): 1})
```

This is where I'm stuck: I do I go from the above to:

```
HAM:3
BAR:3
FOO:3
BAZ:3
NOM:1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do with

```
import collections
collections.Counter(x for x , y in set(my_list) )
Out[251]: Counter({'BAR': 3, 'BAZ': 3, 'FOO': 3, 'HAM': 3, 'NOM': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = {key: len(group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(set(my_list)), key=itemgetter(0))}
print(result)
```

This sorts `my_list` by the first element (the names), partitions it into groups based on those names, and finally gets the name and length of each group as a key-value pair in a `dict`.

Output:

```
{'BAR': 3, 'BAZ': 3, 'FOO': 3, 'HAM': 3, 'NOM': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert List to a Pandas Dataframe, Drop duplicates and Group by Name

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
my_list = [('NOM', datetime.date(2030, 1, 1)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 8)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 10)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('FOO', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAZ', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('BAR', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11)),
 ('HAM', datetime.date(2019, 4, 11))]

# COnvert List of Tuples to Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=['name','date'])
#Remove Duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
#Group by Name Count
df.groupby('name').count()
```